# Is this hard drive EoL?

Tags: hard-drive, hardware

I'm noticing more and more failures in my system during daily use. I feel it could be the hard-drive, could anyone tell me something based on the picture?

HDD in question
[image: HDD in question]

Comment: "Disk is OK", it says.

Comment: What ty[e of failures are you seeing?

Comment: Apparently, there are read and seak errors, ...not sure about feeling anything about it.

Comment: Show us the result after the test is complete. That's only the first 10%.

Comment: Although I don't see evidence of bad sectors, the read/seek error count is nuts. Is this an older drive? HDD or SSD? It may require a firmware update.

Comment: with this amount of R/W errors i think you shuld backup your files and format the harddrive and do a clean install to see if this solves your problem(it probably does not and if not get a new drive)

Answer (score 0):

Diagnostics are not infallible, and errors during use are your best clue.

Make sure to make a backup, nightly, and [verify the backup is accurate](https://superuser.com/questions/218544/is-there-a-copy-and-verify-command-in-ubuntu-linux), until either the failures fade away, or you can replace that drive.